# Raspberry Pi Auto Starting a program

Tags: python, linux, pygame, raspberry-pi

So I have a python game (PyGame) running on a raspberry Pi.

I have followed the instructions found on many sites for getting the Raspberry Pi to auto login (those all work), auto run startx, but I'm stuck on getting my program to run once the GUI loads.

Many people (here on StackOverflow and other places) point to this presentation here:

http://www.slideshare.net/SeggySegaran/raspberry-pi-autostarting-a-python-program

I've tried both ways of doing it (putting the desktop file in autostart or putting the command in rc.local

I have opened up a Terminal window and copy / pasted the command to verify there are no typos and the code will run......

sudo python /home/pi/valley.py

and it will run.  Is there a way to see a log to find out WHY the program doesn't launch?  Is there a better way to get done what I want to get done?

Comment: Why are you running under `sudo`? Does it work without that?

Comment: I was running sudo because that's what the slideshare instructions were.  Will try without.

Answer (score 1):

I've got my python script to run at startup doing this:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

This will allow you to add an element to run when the LXDE desktop session begins (the raspian  default GUI if setup to do from raspi-config)

It will probably have entries like these:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

It's just a matter of adding your script there as well

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@python /home/pi/yourAwesomePyScriptHere.py
```

If your python script uses GPIO, you need to run that as root (using sudo):

```
@sudo python /home/pi/yourGPIOScript.py
```

One thing I do want to point out: **always test your script before hand**.
I mean, run with the absolute path, make sure it still works, try to break it, make sure it's as robust as it can be. If there are errors in your script and you place it at start up you won't see those in a terminal window, but you will hog the cpu with python stuck in a loop at startup.

Also check out this answer on the [RPi exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up/8735)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.  I have been running with the full path.  I will report back when I can get a chance to try it tonight.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it did not work.  The screen just goes blank when I do this and does not do anything.  Like I said, if I type @sudo python /home/pi/myGPIOScript.py everything runs fine.  No errors, it just runs fine.  But if I put this in the autostart, the screen just boots to black.

Comment: are you sure there aren't any errors in the script at all ? Try with a minimal script (that that imports the RPi.GPIO package and prints a message(like the board revision/version)). I'm wondering if there's  an issue running a python script using GPIO in general or if there's something sensitive in your script

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1). Using [LXDE](http://www.megaleecher.net/LXDE_AutoLaunch) autostart.

2). As a [service via init.d](http://www.megaleecher.net/Raspberry_Pi_Autostart#axzz3DFvUNq1A).

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting X with "startx", you can also just stick your game in your .xinitrc.  If your game binary is called "game" and is in your path, just do this:

```
 echo "game" >> ~/.xinitrc
```

This works for other commands.  Add a "&" if you want the command to keep running in the background.

This is how I start my window manager, load my wallpaper, start a compositor, etc.  It is stupid simple, easy to change later, and can do anything you can do at a terminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script automatically on startup of raspberry by using crontab.
Crontab is table that list all command to perform on scheduled time.

First, you need to edit crontab by using:
sudo crontab -e
And after this, add following line:
@reboot python path-of-your-script & (& should be at the end of line that means command will execute in background).

Save your script and reboot your system. When your system will start, your script will run automatically.