# how do I set a program to auto run on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm new to raspberry pi's and Linux in general. I'm setting up some Pi's to access a webpage. I have tried using:
`nano /home/pi/.config/lxsessions/LXDE-pi/autostart`
then adding the line

`@chromium-browser www.etc.com`

but what I found is that while it auto starts chromium, it boots into openbox and the ethernet interface is disabled. I made sure to add
`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp`, but when I reboot again it changes nothing.

So my main question is how do I either make this same thing boot into the desktop AND open chromium, or have chromium startup auto AFTER boot up and log in.

I appreciate any insights and/or help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi Auto Starting a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353134/raspberry-pi-auto-starting-a-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this alongside the GUI using the method below. I had the same issue and this was the only suggested method that worked.

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/myapp.desktop
```

(Replace myapp with the desired file name)

Then add this to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Exec=chromium-browser https://stackoverflow.com
```

Source : https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/how-to/run-script-at-boot-raspberry-pi